# I want to get city, country, state from google analytics object(GA object)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I want to get city,country and state from google analytic object only.
I have setup client id and referrer.

```js
ga(function(tracker) {  
  var client_id = tracker.get('clientId');  
  var referrer = tracker.get('referrer');
  
  
  console.log(client_id);
  console.log(referrer);
  }
```

How can I get this from GA object?

Comment: you might want to try asking here https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Okay I will ask there. Is there any other solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

### You can't.

Your client's IP is sent into GA, and they populate their reports with the best City/State/Country information they can determine for that IP address.